# Problema con Maven y dependencias: Could not resolve dependencies

Tags: java, maven

Estoy intentando de compilar mi proyecto con maven pero me suelta este error al intentar correr la aplicación

```
The POM for jflac:jflac:jar:1.3 is missing, no dependency information 
available
The POM for tritonus:tritonus-dsp:jar:0.3.6 is missing, no dependency 
information available

BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.751s
Finished at: Tue Jul 09 21:23:37 CEST 2019
Final Memory: 9M/309M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal on project DiscordBot: Could not resolve dependencies 
for project com.botdiscord:DiscordBot:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
```

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, el artifact estaba mal puesto

Answer (score 1):

Ya esta solucionado, el artifact estaba mal puesto

```
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
<artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
<version>3.8.3_464</version>
```

```
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>jcenter</id>
<name>jcenter-bintray</name>
<url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
```

Comment: recuerda aceptar tu propia respuesta